# Unable to run project with Jack compiler

Tags: java, android, jack-compiler

I updated my project to use Java 8 and the Jack compiler. The project compiles successfully but whenever I try to run it on a device I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

The full log is as follows:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:transformJackWithJackForDebug'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.sched.util.config.ReflectFactory.create(ReflectFactory.java:98)
    at com.android.jack.ir.ast.JSession.reset(JSession.java:144)
    at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JAstBuilder.compile(JAstBuilder.java:265)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:452)
    at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JAstBuilder.compile(JAstBuilder.java:269)
    at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JackBatchCompiler.performCompilation(JackBatchCompiler.java:219)
    at com.android.jack.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.batch.Main.compile(Main.java:1712)
    at com.android.jack.frontend.java.JackBatchCompiler.compile(JackBatchCompiler.java:184)
    at com.android.jack.Jack.buildSession(Jack.java:1052)
    at com.android.jack.Jack.run(Jack.java:540)
    at com.android.jack.api.v01.impl.Api01ConfigImpl$Api01CompilationTaskImpl.run(Api01ConfigImpl.java:124)
    at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convertUsingJackApis(JackToolchain.java:310)
    at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convertUsingApis(JackToolchain.java:189)
    at com.android.builder.core.JackToolchain.convert(JackToolchain.java:170)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.runJack(JackTransform.java:230)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.JackTransform.transform(JackTransform.java:198)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:185)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2.call(TransformTask.java:181)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:102)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask.transform(TransformTask.java:176)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:163)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:123)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at com.android.sched.vfs.ReadZipFS.createVDir(ReadZipFS.java:263)
    at com.android.sched.vfs.ReadZipFS.createVDir(ReadZipFS.java:53)
    at com.android.sched.vfs.ReadZipFS$ZipVDir.createVDir(ReadZipFS.java:100)
    at com.android.sched.vfs.BaseVDir.createVDir(BaseVDir.java:98)
    at com.android.sched.vfs.PrefixedFS.<init>(PrefixedFS.java:56)
    at com.android.jack.library.v0003.InputJackLibraryImpl.getSectionVFS(InputJackLibraryImpl.java:174)
    at com.android.jack.library.v0003.InputJackLibraryImpl.getDir(InputJackLibraryImpl.java:145)
    at com.android.jack.jayce.TypePackageLoader.<init>(TypePackageLoader.java:34)
    at com.android.sched.util.config.ReflectFactory.create(ReflectFactory.java:90)
    ... 103 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 13.033 secs
```

Prior to using the Jack compiler, everything was fine. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Jack is now deprecated, see [this post](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#disable_jack).

You have to upgrade your Android Studio to 3.0 preview 1, to be able to use Java 8.

If you can't upgrade it (conflict with other lib), or you want to wait for a release version, you can try this workaround solution :

- Add the retrolamba lib, follow [instructions here](https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda).
- Remove this lines if exists from your build.gradle :

  ```
  jackOptions {
      enabled true
  }
  ```
- Sync Project with Gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is a bug on Google's side and it has been reported:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218285

When I encountered this bug, I lowered my Gradle build version to 2.2.2 (or even lower if that doesn't work) and it worked:

*You should find it in `src/build.gradle` file*

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
}
```